# Keeping original column types while updating SQLite DB using Python

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I'm using the `sqlite3` module to update a database and have issues with the column types during the update. Specifically, the columns in the original table (`MY_TABLE`) of the DB have the following types:

{COUNTRY: CHAR(2), POST_CODE: VARCHAR(9), VS_CODE: CHAR(5), LNG: INTEGER}

Here's the code I'm currently using to update the table in the DB with the new information:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv, sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("./test.db")

cols1 = ["COUNTRY", "POST_CODE", "VS_CODE", "LNG"]
df1 = pd.read_csv("./NEW_INFO.csv", sep=";", header=None, names=cols1, encoding="latin1", low_memory=False)
df1.to_sql("MY_TABLE", conn, if_exists="replace", index=False)

conn.close()
```

Although this code doesn't throw any error and successfully writes the new info (from `NEW_INFO.csv`) into the DB, the column types are translated to `TEXT` (first 3 columns) and `REAL` (last column) during the update.

Is there a way to indicate that I want to keep the original column types (or even hardcode the column types that should be used -> but how then)?

Comment: [This doc](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) explains the dynamic typing scheme of sqlite3.

Comment: There are no CHAR and VARCHAR data types in SQLite, although you can use them in the definition of the columns. They are correctly interpreted as TEXT.